# Exception raised was NullPointerException : Cannot get property 'userId' on null object

Tags: playframework

I am very new to play framework. I am trying to get my List displayed in the HTML page, but the code is not working.

Here is the code -

```
public static void allUser(){

    Query query=JPA.em().createQuery("FROM DBUser");
    List users=query.getResultList();
    for(int i=0; i<users.size();i++){
        DBUser user=(DBUser) users.get(i);
        System.out.println(user.getId()+" : "+user.getUsername()+
                " : "+user.getCreatedBy()+" : "+user.getCreatedDate());
        }
    render(users);
}
```

The sysout confirms that my list is not empty.

The HTML page is -

```
<h1>List of all Users in the database</h1> 
<table>
    <tr>
        @for( user <- users){
            <td>${user.userId}</td><td>${user.username}</td><td>${user.createdBy}</td><td>${user.createdDate}</td>
        }
      </tr>
</table>
```

I am very new to scala. So please let me know if I am using correct syntax or not to retrieve list element on HTML page.

Comment: Very interesting mix of Play 1.x templating with Play 2.x version, check the answer of @mgttlinger and/or describe better your problem

Comment: @biesior I guess OP would be the one to clear it up, but I figured it was Play 1.x due to the template syntax and use of `static void` and `render()` method.

Comment: @estmatic - without OP's _better_ description, we can only (arrrgghhh) try to guess where is the problem  :/ Sorry to say that, but I'm starting to think that there are hopeless cases :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the code that worked...Thanks everyone for your comments :)

```
%{
     for(RegisterUser in users) { 
}%
     <tr>
        <td>${RegisterUser.userId}</td><td>${RegisterUser.username}</td>
    </tr>
%{
     }
}%
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to be

```
<h1>List of all Users in the database</h1> 
<table>
    <tr>
        @for( user <- users){
            <td>@user.userId</td><td>@user.username</td><td>@user.createdBy</td><td>@user.createdDate</td>
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `System.out` you are doing `user.getId()` but in your template you are referencing what would be `user.getUserId()`.

If your field is called `id` then your template needs to be:

```
<td>${user.id}</td>
```

Comment: Hi estmatic,
actually in System.out I have created a reference of RegisterUser class as user as shown below->
 RegisterUser user = new RegisterUser();
 users.add(user);
 but and stored them in ArrayList users. But while accessing it on HTML page users is actually a ArrayList of RegisterUser. Thats why it is RegisterUser in users.

sori for the naming convention :(